# How to access Slingshot DLC content?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have this pack installed but cannot seem to access it in any way.

I did notice that a dialog popped up once when I got a Council Transmission, and I elected to take the regular mission - assuming it would show up later - but it hasn't.

Is there a way to experience this extra content, or shall I just keep pressing on and hope that it shows up again at some point?

My progress at the moment is that I've just got the Skeleton Key for the Base Assault mission, so still quite early, but I have done most of the research.

Comment: The XCOM Wikia says if you reject it, it never comes back, although I seem to recall that being patched at some point.

Comment: Yep @agent86. I did search - not very well it seems ;)